# Does dart have a numerical clip function

Tags: integer, dart

I am using Dart to create a simple form-like webapp.

I am doing validation on the input to restrict it to a certain range,
in this case `1-5`

so once it is parsed I have to check the bounds.
I am currently using the ternary operator.

```
  foo = foo <= 0 ? 1 : foo;
  foo = foo > 5 ? 5 : foo;
```

This works, but it isn't particularly clean.

As this seems like it would be a common task in many dart programs I thought it might have a inbuilt function for it.
Is there?

Something like [numpy's clip](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) (to use an example totally unrelated to this domain).

Comment: What about `<input type='number' min='0' max='5'>`

Comment: As far as I can tell setting these constraints doesn't stop the user entering in any number say 32, or indeed entering any string (say "foo"), it just controls the range accessible by clicking on the arrows. Thus further validation and control is required. It would be great if it did work that way bot it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Bother. I would have liked to be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function is also called clamp. Apparently, the function [isn't in the library](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3176&q=clamp&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Area%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified). The linked open enhancement request is for adding generic version of min,max and clamp and mentions that min and max exist for numerical values in [dart:math](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:math). As can be seen from the documentation, clamp, clip or similar isn't there.

If you need it often, you'll have to use your own function. Your implementation is ok, though I would use the existing min and max functions instead of the ternary operator.

EDIT: While there is no free function, num has a clamp method as shown in the documentation, in GameAlchemist's link.

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.num#id_clamp